# How to change line spacing of the label text in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

In every page, the text's line-spacing is too small, how to make it bigger?
[you see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDh1y.jpg)

I found that if I increase the font size, the line-spacing can be larger, but at the same time, the window size increases too.

Comment: Windows version? Do you have the Asian fonts installed?

Comment: Windows 7, Yes Chinese font 宋体

Answer (score 0):

That text is displayed by the Windows [Static control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760769(v=vs.85).aspx). I don't see anything in the [documented styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760773(v=vs.85).aspx) that would change the line spacing. There is `SS_EDITCONTROL` but it does not seem to have any effect on the line spacing:

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!undef __NSD_Label_STYLE
!define __NSD_Label_STYLE ${DEFAULT_STYLES}|${SS_NOTIFY}|${SS_EDITCONTROL}
!undef NSD_CreateLabel
!insertmacro __NSD_DefineControl Label

!include "MUI2.nsh"
...
```

I believe the Static control uses [`DrawText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx) to draw the text and it has a `DT_EXTERNALLEADING` flag that [might change the line height](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/32667/info-font-metrics-and-the-use-of-negative-lfheight) but I don't think there is a way to enable the flag.

Without any further information to go on I have to assume that the Static control is the best way to display this kind of text and that Windows is displaying the text correctly.

If you are not running a Chinese version of Windows then you should make sure that you have the appropriate [language pack and fonts installed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3083806/why-does-some-text-display-with-square-boxes-in-some-apps-on-windows-1) so Windows can use the best available font (Chinese (Simplified) supplemental fonts
& Chinese (Traditional) supplemental fonts). This is [especially important on Windows 10](http://forums.winamp.com/showpost.php?p=3056605&postcount=24) because it removed some of the far east fonts by default.

Comment: My Windows version is Chinese, and NSIS uses "宋体 " by default. I also tried other Chinese Fonts, but It seems that the pages become more ugly.